# Where are the ElasticSearch APIs exposed when running Crate?

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch, crate

I've successfully installed the elasticsearch head plugin on crate and can access its web UI but it fails to connect. I'd like to be able to use it to visualize the data in the underlying elasticsearch store. Is there a a way to access the elasticsearch API directly so that head can work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to enable the API which is done inside the `crate.yml` file. And the setting to change is:

```
es.api.enabled: true
```

However, Elasticsearch Plugins may not work out of the box because Crate and Elasticsearch aren't binary compatible (you will probably have to modify the namespaces and imports). Elasticsearch has a shading step in their maven configuration so the elasticsearch jar contains different namespaces then Crate does (because Crate doesn't use shading).

Comment: Understood, mostly I wanted to know if the APIs were still available. Thanks much!