# Any way to install kibana with elasticsearch's kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, crate

I want to know if is possible to install kibana with the elasticsearch provided by crate. I know that the integration with elasticsearch is done in a low level, but may be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Kibana with Crate if you enable the elasticsearch API. See [Where are the ElasticSearch APIs exposed when running Crate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836683/where-are-the-elasticsearch-apis-exposed-when-running-crate)

Once you've enabled the ES API in Crate you can point the `elasticsearch_url` in the `kibana.yml` to the Crate HTTP endpoint (by default `http://localhost:4200`)

Keep in mind that the Elasticsearch dependency inside Crate may be a bit behind. So after new Kibana or Elasticsearch releases it could take a while until Crate has caught up.

Comment: There is also a thread on this in our Google Group: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/crateio/FbX-XkCcdzY

I have not tested this myself, but I'm interested in doing so. Maybe myself or someone else here at Crate can spend some time to give it a try with the latest versions.